# EF The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So I'm looking for a way in EntityFramework to do a string Comparison on TEXT Sql Field.

Every Solution I see to this problem tells them to Switch the Database Field from TEXT to nvarchar, which I cannot do.

This Code may seem intimidating but all of this works except for the line specified

```
var TitlesData = Mod.Titles.AsNoTracking().Where(t => !t.isTrackedMMS )
    .Select(t => new
    {
        MK3ID = t.ID,
        ExtTitleID = t.ExtTitleID,
        CompletedSteps = new List<bool> { 
            true,
        (t.TitleClasses.Any() || t.TitleToSearsTaxonomies.Any()),
        (t.MediaDetailsStorages.Any(m => m.FK_StoreName == 2 || m.FK_StoreName == 3)),
        (t.MediaDetails.FirstOrDefault().MasterDelivered.HasValue),
        (t.MediaDetails.FirstOrDefault().MasterReceived.HasValue),
        (t.MediaDetails.FirstOrDefault().Datecaptured.HasValue),
        (t.MediaDetails.FirstOrDefault().DVDCreated.HasValue || !t.MediaDetails.FirstOrDefault().CreateDVD),

        //This Line Throws an Error
        (t.FullDescriptionHTML != ""),

    }.Where(b => b).Count(),
        SkipCollections = (t.ProductsToTitles.Any() || t.RoyaltyContract.ProductsToContracts.Any()),
        SkipSegments = t.ByPassSegment.HasValue ? t.ByPassSegment.Value : false,
        SkipEcom = t.Items.All(i => i.BlockFromSale.HasValue ? i.BlockFromSale.Value : false),
        SentTrackingItems = t.SentTrackingEmails.Select(e => e.TrackingActionID).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Does anybody know a way to do a string compare on The FullDescription html field

Thanks

Comment: Use a store function?

Comment: If you were to change the line to `t.FullDescriptionHTML != null`, would that be good enough?

Comment: This is an issue in the Database, not in your application; `Text` is considered Large Object Data, and is not indexable/searchable.  It is also being depreciated, and not recommended for use in new development work.  As @AnnL. stated, you can check for the presence of a value, but not check for equality of content.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: I was trying to check for null but entries are submitted as blanks instead so checking for null doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you dont have control of the database so how about comparing the length of the field to zero instead of an empty string

```
(len(t.FullDescriptionHTML) > 0
```

or doing a check for existence if comparing to null. Doing both might be a good idea?

Comment: What DLL is that in for linq?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `(t.FullDescriptionHTML.Length > 0)` because the len is a SQL function, but it didnt work either.  Thanks thou

Comment: HaHa Yip, guess who hasn't stuck his head outside the DB for a while, thx for correcting me.